# RTMP request with body

Tags: streaming, rtmp

I used to watch online streaming videos by using mobile app, and would like to get its real streaming url for playing in VLC media player on my computer.

The following is the screenshot of captured network packet of the streaming video:
[RTMP streaming scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9649.png)

I tried to use VLC media player to play "**tcUrl**" part of the screenshot, but it failed to open this MRL...

I noticed that when mobile app sends out this RTMP request, it has **RTMP body**.

Is there any way that I can send out RTMP request with Body in VLC player? or is there any other tool capable to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the `play` command, which specifies the stream.

The `tcUrl` is similar to a `directory`, and the `play` command specifies the stream like `file`.

Compare to the HTTP URL:

```
http://server/dir/livestream.flv
rtmp://server/dir/livestream
```

The `tcUrl` is `rtmp://server/dir` and the stream is `livestream`. Then you could play or forward if you get the entire url, for example:

```
ffplay rtmp://server/dir/livestream
ffmpeg -f flv -i rtmp://server/dir/livestream -c copy dvr.mp4
```

You could use VLC to play the RTMP url also.